# jQuery form validation with input color

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, input

I want to validate empty input field with jQuery, just like on this website  [vk.com](http://vk.com)

I like the effect when you submit the form on this website, the input is becoming red for a moment and gradually getting its initial color. You can watch this yourself

[Here is video of this validation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d8cdASlJ4ow)

Comment: It's not a problem, try by yourself and paste code, maybe we help you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Jquery` and add `error` on submit and after 1 second remove that class.

For transition effect you can use css3 background-color transition to `error` class.

For example, refer below code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#login_button").click(function() {
    var phoneEmail = $("#phone_email");
    if(!phoneEmail.val()) {
      phoneEmail.addClass('error');
      setTimeout(function(){
        phoneEmail.removeClass('error');
      }, 1000);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
input {
  -webkit-transition: background-color 1s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: background-color 1s ease-out;
  -o-transition: background-color 1s ease-out;
  transition: background-color 1s ease-out;
}

input.error {
  background: #f3765b;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" id="phone_email" placeholder="Phone or email">
  <input type="password" id="pass" placeholder="password">  
  <button id="login_button">Log in</button>  
</form>
```

Comment: It is looking nice, I will try add some gradual change of color though

Comment: transition: 'background-color 1s ease-in-out',
                  "background-color": "red"

Comment: @kilogram yeah, you can modify it according (y).

Comment: @kilogram I made some changes too, see if updated answer help you a bit more.

Comment: This is just what I wanted. It is looking fantastic. Thank you my friend.

Comment: You can upvote if you have gained the Vote Up privilege, awarded at 15 reputation.

Comment: I cannot upvote my friend I just started with this website

Comment: @kilogram you can accept answer as you asked question - http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers :)

Comment: Ha ha... ok! I did that

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
//check if input is empty    
$('.someinputs').each(function(){
          if($(this).val() == 0 || $(this).val() == '') {
            $(this).addClass('empty_field');
          }
          else {
            $(this).removeClass('empty_field');
          }
        });

//this function lights field which have class '.empty_field'
function lightEmpty(){
                $('.empty_field').each(function(){                      
                   $(this).css('border','2px solid #d8512d');
                });
                setTimeout(function(){
                $('.empty_field').each(function(){                        
                  $(this).css('border','1px solid #cdcdcd');
                });
              },1500);
}

//this triggers lightEmpty()
if (emptyInputs.length != 0)
    {
        lightEmpty();
    }
```

It's just changing border of inputs with specific color for time which you can write in setTimeout function. I think you can figure out where to use this code

Comment: Thank you very much but I do not want borders. Previous example is good

Comment: It is close to what i see on vk.com